# ValueError: Shapes (3, 5) and (3, 8, 8, 5) are incompatible, here i am creating an cnn based architecture to recognize face so where size is wrong

Tags: deep-learning

```
from keras.layers.core import Dropout
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
import os
 
dir1 = r"E:\\Dataset\\Train"
dir2 = r"E:\\Dataset\\Test"
catg = ["Deepshika", "Kuldeep", "Lokesh", "Neelu", "ojasvi"]

dic = {
    "Deepshika" : 0,
    "Kuldeep"   : 1,
    "Lokesh"    : 2,
    "Neelu"     : 3, 
    "ojasvi"    : 4
}

train_data = [ ]
train_labels = [ ]


test_data = [ ]
test_labels = [ ]


def creat_train_dataset( ):
    
    for cat in catg :
        path = os.path.join(dir1, cat)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            image = load_img(os.path.join(path, img),target_size= (120, 120) )
            image = img_to_array(image)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            train_data.append(image)
            train_labels.append(dic[cat])

def creat_test_dataset( ):
    
    for cat in catg :
        path = os.path.join(dir2, cat)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            image = load_img(os.path.join(path, img),target_size= (120, 120) )
            image = img_to_array(image)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            test_data.append(image)
            test_labels.append(dic[cat])


creat_train_dataset( )
creat_test_dataset( )

# dataset generation 

x_train = np.array(train_data[0:150], dtype = 'float32')/255
y_train = np.array(train_labels[0:150], dtype = 'int') 
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels[0:150], 5)
print("x train shape: ", x_train.shape)

x_test = np.array(test_data[0:50], dtype = 'float32')/255 
y_test = np.array(test_labels[0:50], dtype = 'int') 
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels[0:50], 5)
print("x test shape: ", x_test.shape)

mp.imshow(x_train[121])
print(y_train[121])
mp.show( )

batch_size = 3
im_shape = (120, 120, 1)

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], *im_shape)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], *im_shape)

print('x_train shape:' , x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:' , x_test.shape)

print('y_train shape:' , y_train.shape)
print('y_test shape:' , y_test.shape)
#creating the architecture 

cnn_radheKrishna = Sequential()
cnn_radheKrishna.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 5, activation = 'relu', input_shape = im_shape))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(BatchNormalization( ))

cnn_radheKrishna.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(BatchNormalization( ))

cnn_radheKrishna.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 3))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(BatchNormalization( ))

cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dense(2048, activation = 'relu'))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dropout(0.5))


cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dense(1024, activation = 'relu'))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dropout(0.5))

cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))

optimiser = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate= 0.0001)

cnn_radheKrishna.compile(optimizer = optimiser, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

cnn_radheKrishna.summary( )

info = cnn_radheKrishna.fit(np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train), batch_size= 3, epochs= 100)

cnn_radheKrishna.save('hari.h5')

score = cnn_radheKrishna.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

print('test los {}'.format(score[0]))
print('test acc {}'.format(score[1]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of image classification one of the important thing to remember while connecting Convolutional layer output to Dense layer is to make sure Flatten the output of the Convolutional layer then pass it to Dense layer. Just add following code snippets just before your 1st Dense layer containing 2048 neurons.

````
cnn_radheKrishna.add(BatchNormalization( ))

cnn_radheKrishna.add(Flatten( )) # As your import statement contains Flatten layer

cnn_radheKrishna.add(Dense(2048, activation = 'relu'))
```
````

Comment: thankyou very much for helping me out

Comment: can you please tell me that when i am using same model for predicting using single image array then it is showing ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3, i have saved the trained model and loaded it and then used predict for one image

Comment: test = load_model('hari.h5')
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 120, 120, 1)

y = test.predict(x_test[21]) so for this above error is coming

Comment: Tensorflow expect input always in batch format even in prediction time too. So even if you want to pass single image from array of multiple images use like this  **y = test.predict(x_test[21:22])**

Comment: If you load single image into numpy array make sure to reshape into batch format with shape of (1, 120, 120, 1)

Comment: yes i have reshaped it but if i using loading single image only then x_test[0:1] will work?

Comment: if you reshape the image with (1, 120, 120, 1) then don't use x_test[0:1] directly pass x_test. Use x_test[0:1] in case of your numpy array contains more than one image

Comment: Sir on the test data the accuracy is around 80% and i have taken 30 facial images for each individual in train dataset and 10 in test dataset but if i am using images other than this data then model cannot predict correctly, so can guide me how to improve upon its accuracy.